# What is the correct way to provision an azure app service instance with ACR access?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, terraform, azure-container-registry

I have been banging my head against the wall of this since yesterday. I have read some SO posts and googled around but I cant seem to get this to work. I want to provision and app service instance in my azure account and I want it to be able to run docker images and pull docker images from an azure container registry. Furthermore I want to do all of this with terraform. What is the correct way to accomplish this? The terraform that I have written looks like this so far, but as mentioned does not work. I get an error

> ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and
> credentials (if using private repository)

Here is the terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "both_rg" {
  name     = "dpt-both"
  location = "West US"
}


resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "dpt_both_appservice_plan" {
  name                = "dpt-app-service-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.both_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.both_rg.name
  kind                = "Linux"
  reserved            = true

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "B1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "dpt_app_service" {
  name                = "dpt-app-service"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.both_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.both_rg.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.dpt_both_appservice_plan.id
  site_config {
    always_on = false
    linux_fx_version  = "DOCKER|dptacr.azurecr.io/dpt-images:latest"
  }

  app_settings = {
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL      = "https://dptacr.azurecr.io"
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME = "<acr username>"
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD = "<acr password>"
  }

}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "dpt_acr" {
  name                     = "dptAcr"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.both_rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.both_rg.location
  sku                      = "Basic"
  admin_enabled            = true
  public_network_access_enabled = true
}
```

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your Terraform code. Here is the screenshot that uses the Terraform code pull from the Azure App Service:

[image]

[image]

So the possible reason the credential for the ACR is not exactly right. There are two ways to get the username and password. One is that uses the admin credential. You navigate to the ACR **Access keys**, then there is the admin username and password. If not enabled, then enable it. The other one is that use the service principle with the right permissions, then the username is the app id and the password is the secret. Get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication).

Comment: This confirmed it for me. The problem that I was actually having was my images were not getting tagged right during the docker build step. Then when referencing them in the deploy step it wasnt working. What was wierd was the authentication error... Anyways works now